# Como fazer todos os caracteres ficarem numa mesma altura

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou querendo colocar todos os elementos de uma div numa mesma altura, que nem nessa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu até o momento está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="conteudo-banner">
        <h1>Kerline</h1>
        <div class="code-logo">
            <span>&lt;</span>
            <span>/</span>
            <span>Code</span>
            <span>&gt;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Meu CSS:

```
.banner{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 98px 0 240px;
}

.conteudo-banner{
    margin-top: 65px;
}

.conteudo-banner h1{
    font-family: techno_hideo;
    font-size: 13.5em;
    color:#000000 ;
    text-align: center;
}

.code-logo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20em;
}

.conteudo-banner .code-logo span{
    font-size: 6.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.conteudo-banner .code-logo span:nth-child(1),
.conteudo-banner .code-logo span:nth-child(2),
.conteudo-banner .code-logo span:nth-child(4){
    color:#292570;
    font-size: 7.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.conteudo-banner .code-logo span:nth-child(3){
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
.conteudo-banner .code-logo span:nth-child(2){
    font-size: 6em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:-4px; 
}
```

font-size -  Regula o tamanho da fonte
display - Deixa o span na mesma linha mas com opções block
position - Possível manipular o elemento para cima e para baixo
top - Distancia em relação ao topo

Assim você consegue alinhar de acordo com a sua fonte, como a fonte que estou usando é diferente fica mais fácil para você fazer os ajustes.

Fiz um pequeno exemplo alinhando a / (Barra) : https://jsfiddle.net/uy02om17/